# Execute jQuery when objects are in viewport with a single script targeting multiple objects each

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, animate.css

I'm looking for a simple jQuery plugin that detects if the given objects are within the viewport or not. Based upon true, execute javascript, changing their CSS appearances, such as `opacity` and `translate3D`.

I currently have tried all jQuery plugins from [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/5-jquery-viewport-plugins/), these include the `viewport selector`, `jQuery bullseye`, `Within viewport`, `jQuery viewportOffset` and `jQuery.viewport` jQuery plugins. However, I've also tried the `inView` jQuery plugin, but none of them are working. Probably because of the following.

The problem I'm currently having is that I would like to have a single script that targets all objects with a given class and execute Javascript(-> Change CSS appearances) to each of them when `pseudo code: 'In viewport? :true`. All scripts I've tried only target the first object with the given class and ignore all the others.

So who can would write a piece of code or link me a plugin and include a short script that targets all `img.fadeIn' individually and change their opacity to '1' when they are in the viewport? And it would be great if the javascript gets executed not when the whole object is visible, but at least 50% of it.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you've got the objects inside the viewport selected in a jQuery object, most jQuery methods do target everything. For instance: `$('img.fadeIn').css({'opacity': 1});`

Comment: Strangely, the appearances only change of the first, instead of all of them. Though, all objects are spread over the whole page, not all within a single viewport size together.

Comment: Are you sure that all of them are selected?

Comment: They all have the same class. I assume it does not matter whether a difference Z-index, or the ID of their parent (these are different). But I can check the element and see the opacity remain on zero, as set in the css

Comment: Well, I would test these things in the inspector. In Chrome or Safari, right-click, go Inspect Element, find the console, and try running some of these things, to see the results.